# Post a file from pages.app to a Yahoo! group

Tags: ipad, pages, file, yahoo

My wife and I can't figure out how to post a file from the Pages.app on her iPad to a Yahoo! group.  From Pages.app, she can email the file to herself, but can't post it to the file sharing section of Yahoo! groups.

Since she got it, my wife has been working diligently to ditch her laptop and go iPad only.  Until now, nearly everything she needs to do has been doable.  Some things are harder, but almost always, they are "doable."  This is the first time we couldn't find a solution without using a laptop.

The file that needs to be posted are PTA meeting minutes (taken directly on the iPad in Pages.app) and the Yahoo! group is one that was created years ago and is already well established for the PTA (i.e., We can't move the whole PTA over to another service like iCloud).

Any suggestions out there?

Comment: It's not a real answer, but she might float a suggestion if anyone would also benefit to a switch to dropbox. She might not be the only PTA member with an iPad.

Comment: Good suggestion.  But the Yahoo! group is used for more than just files (Calendaring, email, etc.).  Haven't used Dropbox in a while, but I think those are a few more features than Dropbox offers.  What is really needed here is access to files stored on the iPad from a browser on the iPad.  Not sure if Apple is ever going to allow that (Android does!).

Comment: I'm not familiar with yahoo groups, but couldn't it upload a file to dropbox and just send a link to the file? At worst, someone from a computer would see the file and finish the upload if you couldn't review things by passing around links rather than the entire file. Sorry, I don't mean to offer workarounds, but I've seen that work in many cases where a custom workflow software doesn't accept emailed attachments for delivery from devices that don't support direct upload.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try exporting as ms word files or PDF files and then uploading that to yahoo!group? If all things fail there is still the snap shop option of taking a screenshot of the document and uploading as a jpg graphics file. You can take screenshots by holding down the on and home button *at the same time.

Comment: No, we didn't try exporting to MS Word or PDF (of course, we can do it on our Mac).  But, wouldn't the new PDF or MS Word file still be "trapped" in the iPad with no way to access it from a browser?

Comment: The screenshot method would likely work for a simple document as iOS allows the upload of pictures on the device.  But for obvious reasons (hopefully), this NOT ideal.

Comment: There are several ways to "get the file out" You can always use the email option to get the PDF from pages out into the world. Or you can open it with the "open with another application" option in iBook, kindle or some msword friendly apps like docToGo. Then there is the iTunes option. The screenshot method is really a last resort option if you are in a bind and need something quickly.

Comment: Thanks.  Basically that is what she ended up doing.  Except that she emailed it to herself and used a non iOS device to actually upload the file to the proper place on the website/group.